# rich:modalPanel reloading page on hide

Tags: jsf, richfaces, modal-dialog

I have a JSF page using richfaces with a few help buttons like this:

```
<rich:componentControl for="panelHelp" event="oncomplete" operation="show" />
```

The panel called is this:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="panelHelp" minHeight="250" minWidth="500"
    keepVisualState="true" resizeable="true" moveable="true">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Help" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:commandLink value="">
            <h:graphicImage value="/close2.png" title="Close" />
            <rich:componentControl for="panelHelp" event="onclick" operation="hide" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
        <h:outputText escape="false" id="txtHelp"
        value="#{msgHelp}" style="width: 100%; height: 190px" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

However, whenever I press the button to close the panel, it reloads the whole page, instead of simply hiding the panel.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

I'm using richfaces version 3.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a4j:commandLink instead of h:commandLink and provide an a4j:support as well. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's reloading the entire page because of your use of the `<h:commandLink/>`, which is going to trigger the entire JSF request processing lifecycle. To get your desired results you don't need the command link component. All you really need is:

```
<f:facet name="controls">
    <h:graphicImage id="closeButton" value="/close2.png" title="Close" />
    <rich:componentControl attachTo="closeButton" for="panelHelp" event="onclick" operation="hide" />
</f:facet>
```

What we're doing here is firing the `<rich:componentControl/>` on click of the image; there's no need for a link. I'm assuming you're using Richfaces 3.X. (RF 4.X has deprecated the `attachTo` attribute)

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.3, I'll add the information to the question, as I didn't know the version was this relevant. Still, this did not work, and the page still reloaded upon pressing the close button.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer will work in Richfaces 3.x, If you are using Richfaces 4.x then the given code will work.

```
<f:facet name="controls">
    <h:graphicImage value="/close2.png" >
        <rich:componentControl target="closeButton" operation="hide" event="click" />
    </h:graphicImage>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: Since I'm using version 3.3.3, this only made the button disappear, but it sure didn't hurt to try :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `disableDefault="true"` attribute to your `rich:componentControl` to disable default behavior of the link on click.

Comment: Still reloaded after adding this.

Comment: @fcm Are you sure you deploy the changes to server properly? E.g. kolossus's answer even does not have a link so there is nothing which could cause page refresh.

Comment: Pretty sure I did it. Haseeb's answer had an impact, for instance, although it didn't work because of version incompatibilities